# Drop years before 2000 in R

Tags: r

I am currently doing some research on corporate lobbying spending using the OpenSecrets Bulk Data. I have an organized data set but it spans from 1998-2020. I would like to drop the years 1998 and 1999. What code should I be running to just drop those two years?
Currently my code looks like this:

```
lob_indus <- read_csv("lobby/lob_indus.txt", quote="|",
                      col_names=c("client", "sub", "total", "year",
                                  "Catcode"))
lob_indus <- bind_rows(lob_indus)
```

I would just like to remove any observation where year < 2000 ! for some reason really struggling with this!

Comment: `... %>% filter(!year %in% 1998:1999)` (literal, specific) or `... %>% filter(year > 1999)`. (I'm assuming `library(dplyr)`, since your code suggests you're using packages from the tidyverse.)

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to solve this, one in base R is this:

```
# dummy data
lob_indus <- data.frame(year = c(1999, 2000, 2001),
                        value = c("a","b", "c"))

# filter the values you want (all larger than 1999)
lob_indus[lob_indus$year > 1999,]

  year value
2 2000     b
3 2001     c
```